# Слияние массивов с особым фильтром (php)

Tags: php, массивы

**Всем привет! Нужно выполнить слияние двух массивов через одного, важно не нарушать порядок значений**

Вот у меня есть 2 массива, один например с шрифтами, другой с цветом шрифтов:

```
Array (
[1] => Times new roman;
[2] => Arial Black;
[3] => Montserrat;
)
```

И второй массив

```
Array (
[1] => color:green;
[2] => color:black;
[3] => color:orange;
)
```

Конечный результат который мне нужно получить

```
Array (
[1] => Times new roman;
[2] => color:green;
[3] => Arial Black;
[4] => color:black;
[5] => Montserrat;
[6] => color:orange;
)
```

*Offtop: просьба не оставлять молча отрицательные реакции, а нормально помочь, я мучаюсь с этим уже второй день, перед тем как писать что вы нашли ответ по первому результату в гугле подумайте, это то что мне нужно?*

Заранее спасибо

Comment: если вы не приведете код ваших попыток решить задачу то вас заминусуют а вопрос закроют. закроют согласно правилам.

Comment: количество элементо одинаково? - да.  длина известна? -да. Цикл от 0 до n-1 написать можем? если не можем то читаем про циклы. Добавлять элементы в новый массив умеем? последовательно добавить сначала с первого а потом со второго можем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
<?php
//Массив шрифтов
$fontsArr = [ 'Times new roman', 'Arial Black', 'Montserrat'];
//Массив цветов
$colorsArr = ['color:green', 'color:black', 'color:orange'];
//Выходной массив
$outArr = [];
//в цикле перебираем массив шрифтов
foreach( $fontsArr as $index => $fontName ) {
    //$index это номер позиции названия шрифта в массиве $fontsArr т.е 0, 1 ...
    //$fontName это название шрифта на соответствующей позиции в массиве $fontsArr т.е 'Times', 'Arail' ...

    //Проверяем, что кол-во элементов в массиве цветов не меньше чем в массиве названий шрифтов
    if ( $index < count( $colorsArr ) ) {
        //В выходной массив добавляем новый элемент с названием шрифта
        $outArr[] = $fontName;
        //В выходной массив добавляем новый элемент с цветом шрифта (берем его по номеру позиции элемента в массиве цветов)
        $outArr[] = $colorsArr[ $index ];
        //Т.е мы взяли первый элемент из массив названий шрифтов и добавили его в выходной массив
        //после чего зная номер позиции элемента из массива шрифтов добавили в выходной массив
        //элемент из массива цветов шрифтов с точно таким же номером позиции
    }
}        

print_r( $outArr );
```

Результат:

```
Array
( 
  [0] => Times new roman 
  [1] => color:green 
  [2] => Arial Black 
  [3] => color:black 
  [4] => Montserrat 
  [5] => color:orange 
)
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за развернутый, качественный и что редко для этого форума - адекватный ответ. Все отлично работает спасибо большое, вроде как отметил ответ решенным